# How to add a continue to an if block

Tags: python, if-statement

How would I add a continue into the `class_ = eqid if eqid in allowed_classes else default_class` I don't understand that kind of if statement, I need to add a continue as `if eqid == allowed_classes` then I want the while loop to stop, I also only want it to print the selected class if `eqid == allowed_classes`

```
allowed_classes = set(["N001", "N002", "N003", "N004", "E001", "E002", "E003"])  # etc
default_class = "N004" #If no class is specified it is defaulted to N004

eqid = raw_input('Please swipe your card: ').strip().upper()
class_ = eqid if eqid in allowed_classes else default_class
print("Selected class", class_)
```

I have tried

```
eqid = raw_input('Please swipe your card: ').strip().upper()
if eqid in allowed_classes 
    class_ = eqid
    print('Selected class: ', class_)
else default_class
```

but that doesn't work, won't even run.

FULL CODE:

```
import csv
import datetime
import os

#Defaults
allowed_classes = set(["N001", "N002", "N003", "N004", "E001", "E002", "E003"])  # etc
default_class = "N004" #If no class is specified it is defaulted to N004

while (1):

    #Magnetic Card Reader Output & Attendance (Default = 0)
    attendance = '0'
    eqid = raw_input('Please swipe your card: ').strip().upper()
    class_ = eqid if eqid in allowed_classes else default_class
    print("Selected class", class_)


    #Day & Time Checker
    format = "%H%M%S"
    format_ = "%H%M"
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    s = today.strftime(format) #Time in 24hour
    s2 = today.strftime(format_)
    d = datetime.datetime.today().weekday() #Day of week (0-5)
    period = 0 #If they scan it outside of the dedicated periods it defaults to period 1

    #Period Checker
    if "084500" < s < "094000":
        period = 0
    if "094000" < s < "104000":
        period = 1
    if "112000" < s < "121500":
        period = 2
    if "121500" < s < "131500":
        period = 3
    if "133500" < s < "143000":
        period = 4

    #Class Code Reader
    dataList = []
    with open('J:/attendance/Timetables/'+class_+'.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
      csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      for row in csvreader:
         dataList.append(row)
    csvfile.close()

    #Class Code
    clcode = dataList[period][d] 

    #CSV Writer
    ofile = open('Attendance.csv', "a")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow([eqid, period+1, clcode, attendance]) 
    ofile.close()
```

(It is formatted correctly just can't get it formatted in here sorry :/)

Comment: in the `else` statement you are not assigning the value to `class_`. try `else: class_ = default_class`

Comment: It's called a ternary. If you want to break/continue a loop, you cannot use that syntax

Comment: "doesn't work, won't even run"... Well, you have a syntax error. If statements and else statements are ended by colon characters

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you, I got the code from another question I asked, thought It had to have a colon, thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but...   I suggest you read "[mcve]" --- you've included a lot of code that has _nothing_ to do with your question, which makes it harder for us to find the parts you're asking about.  (Also, creating the MCVE often reveals your problem before the process is done... although probably not in _this_ case.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I only add my full code at the end as other question I have asked I have gotten answers that don't because they didn't have the full code, either that or my explaining is really bad, I'll keep it t a minimal next time, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't do that.  You're confusing the `ternary operator` with an `if statement`, likely because they have some syntax similarity.  The ternary operator returns one of two expressions based on a condition:

```
expr1 if condition else expr2
```

This is an *expression*, not a *statement block*.  You cannot add a `continue` to an expression.

Instead, you'll have to use the full form:

```
if eqid in allowed_classes:
    class_ = eqid
    print('Selected class: ', class_)
    continue
else:
    class_ = default_class
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes that Is what I need, thank you :D was it the `else:` and `class_ default_class` that I was missing? everything else looks the same too me.

Comment: Note that the `else` is not strictly necessary, as execution will not continue past the `if` portion of the loop body if the condition is true.

Comment: Yeah I did remove the `else`

Comment: Code markup should be used for actually code. But if you're simply trying to add emphasis to a phrase - as I believe you're doing here -, you should use regular mark-up instead. That's why I changed "`ternary operator` with an `if statement`" to `"_ternary operator_ with an _if statement_"`. If that's the case, feel free to leave it as is. Otherwise, please remove the code mark-up and use regular mark-up instead.